# Change icon of an Executable Jar File

Tags: java

Is there anyway to give Executable jar another image than the defult image

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications. One of its features is the support of custom application icon with multiple resolutions and color depths.

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems/desktop managers do this differently.  It's not done via Java or the .jar manifest.

Comment: @lalit What Jeremy is saying that each OS or desktop manager don't deal with changing the jar's icon. In other words, what you'd have to do on Windows would not work with Mac

Comment: @lalit don't deal with changing jar's icon the same way, I mean. **