# Turning Java code into a program?

Tags: java, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make executable program in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093763/how-to-make-executable-program-in-java)

I would like to know how I can open my GUI program without going through the terminal? It being independent, and simply having to click on an icon and it open it.

Comment: Duplicate, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093763/how-to-make-executable-program-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148111/java-executable-jar-creation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083586/java-executable-jar-files

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a jar file, you can do this with the following command

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

The options and arguments used in this command are:

The c option indicates that you want to create a JAR file.

The f option indicates that you want the output to go to a file rather than to stdout.

jar-file is the name that you want the resulting JAR file to have. You can use any filename for a JAR file. By convention, JAR filenames are given a .jar extension, though this is not required.

The input-file(s) argument is a space-separated list of one or more files that you want to include in your JAR file.

The input-file(s) argument can contain the wildcard * symbol. If any of the "input-files" are directories, the contents of those directories are added to the JAR archive recursively.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a `jar` file. See the [Creating a JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) Java tutorial.